# PHP Wordpress odbc_connect() : "Error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect()"

Tags: php, linux, odbc, apache2, unixodbc

I have a custom plugin in **Wordpress 6.0.2**, programmed with **PHP 8.1**.

When I run the function:

`$conn = odbc_connect($DNS, "", "");`

Returns the following error:

***Error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect()***

The server where the website (and the plugin) is hosted has the Linux **Ubuntu 18.04** operating system.

I have installed all the necessary dependencies and libraries (and more), but it keeps showing the same error all the time:

`sudo apt-get install libc6 libstdc++6 zlib1g libgcc1`

`sudo apt-get install unixODBC unixODBC-dev`

`sudo apt-get install php-odbc` or `sudo apt-get install php8.1-odbc`

Everything is installed correctly, the driver too (and it is also configured correctly):

[Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAO0i.png)

The code is correct, it works locally. And the error has nothing to do with the Driver or the connection parameters. It has to do with it not detecting the **"odbc_connect()"** function.

What can be the solution? Does anyone have any idea what might be missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you're using odbc_connect. Try odbc_pconnect, maybe it's better for servers.

Comment: No man, with function odbc_pconnect is the same error...